# How to solve NoClassDefFoundError: Apache Commons Lang Android

Tags: java, android, apache-commons-lang3

I'm receiving this exception when I try to use `DateUtils.addMinutes()`:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.apprainha, PID: 7742
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.lang3.-$$Lambda$Validate$XJJZURDO20sZXXyZMfTRRv13t2c
        at org.apache.commons.lang3.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:225)
        at org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils.validateDateNotNull(DateUtils.java:1789)
        at org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils.add(DateUtils.java:515)
        at org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils.addMinutes(DateUtils.java:472)
        at com.example.apprainha.threads.ExportaDados.exportCSVs(ExportaDados.java:187)
        at com.example.apprainha.threads.ExportaDados.doInBackground(ExportaDados.java:60)
        at com.example.apprainha.threads.ExportaDados.doInBackground(ExportaDados.java:33)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

My code is calling `DateUtils.addminutes()` to add 1 minute to variable `date` like this:

```
Date target = DateUtils.addminutes(date, 1);
```

I put the right dependency on my Gradle file:

```
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.11'
```

I researched a lot about this error and none of the solutions mentioned in another posts solve my problem. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your grade file to this:

```
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6'
```

then you can use this import in your classes:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
```

Comment: For the record, I changed the Apache Commons version on Gradle, from 3.11 to 3.6, like @saon_srabon recommended. This change solved the problem.